# UWP : how can I change UI from another XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a UWP application:

[image: scheme]

My app command bar (XAML 2) manages TabView content (XAML 1). I need different command bars for different tab types. Now I using several frames in second XAML, and I can't change it from XAML 1.

How I can change XAML 2 UI from XAML 1 `.cs` file?

Thanks for any help.

UPD:
I have main XAML:

```
<Page
        x:Class="Test.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:NetChrom"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    
        <Grid x:Name="BaseGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!-- titlebar -->
                <RowDefinition x:Name="Titlebar" Height="30">
                </RowDefinition>
                <!-- toolbar -->
                <RowDefinition x:Name="Toolbar" Height="110">
                </RowDefinition>
                <!-- main window -->
                <RowDefinition>
                </RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
            <Grid x:Name="TitlebarGrid" Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*">
                    </ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <local:TitleBar/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="ToolbarGrid" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="37*">
                    </ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="27*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!-- toolbar -->
                <local:Toolbar Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            </Grid>
    
    
            <!-- content-->
            <Grid x:Name="MainContent" Grid.Row="2" Background="AliceBlue">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="325" MinWidth="120">
    
                    </ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition>
    
                    </ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="#F3F3F3">
                    <local:MainTabbar/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="LightBlue">
                    <local:FileManager/>
                </Grid>
                <controls:GridSplitter
                    Margin="0,10,10,0"
                    Opacity="0"
                    Background="Transparent" 
                    GripperCursor="Default"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    ResizeDirection="Auto"
                    ResizeBehavior="BasedOnAlignment"
                    CursorBehavior="ChangeOnSplitterHover"
                    Width="0">
                        <controls:GridSplitter.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="-8" />
                        </controls:GridSplitter.RenderTransform>
                </controls:GridSplitter>
            </Grid>
            
        </Grid>
    </Page>
```

and in this XAML there are two another XAML: MainTabbar (XAML 1) and Toolbar (XAML 2) from scheme.

This is Toolbar.xaml:

```
    <UserControl
        x:Class="Test.Toolbar"
        x:Name="toolbarControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
        xmlns:local="using:Test"
        xmlns:met="using:Test.Method"
        xmlns:chr="using:Test.ChrOptions"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
        d:DesignHeight="110"
        d:DesignWidth="1920">
        <Border CornerRadius="0,0,10,10" BorderBrush="#D4D4D4" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Background="#F3F3F3">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="110">
                    </RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
                <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition>
                        </ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="320"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                        <Frame x:Name="toolbarFrame"/> <!-- cmdbar frame>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
    
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </UserControl>
```

This is MainTabbar:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Test.MainTabbar"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Test"
    xmlns:met="using:Test.Method"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    d:DesignWidth="1595">

    <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0">
        <muxc:TabView x:Name="Tabs" 
                             IsAddTabButtonVisible="False"
                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                             TabCloseRequested="Tabs_TabCloseRequested"
                             AllowDropTabs="True"
                             CanDragTabs="False"
                             CanReorderTabs="True"
                             TabDroppedOutside="Tabs_TabDroppedOutside"
                             TabStripDragOver="Tabs_TabStripDragOver"
                             TabStripDrop="Tabs_TabStripDrop"
                             TabDragStarting="Tabs_TabDragStarting" >
            <muxc:TabView.TabItems>
                <muxc:TabViewItem Header="SampleMethod.met" IsClosable="False">
                    <muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                        <muxc:SymbolIconSource Symbol="Placeholder" />
                    </muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                   <!-- <Frame x:Name="MethodFrame"/> -->
                    <met:MethodTabView/>
                </muxc:TabViewItem>
                <muxc:TabViewItem Header="SampleChrome.chr" IsClosable="False">
                    <muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                        <muxc:SymbolIconSource Symbol="Placeholder" />
                    </muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                    <local:ChrView/>
                </muxc:TabViewItem>
            </muxc:TabView.TabItems>
            <muxc:TabView.TabStripHeader>
                <Grid x:Name="ShellTitlebarInset" Background="#F3F3F3" />
            </muxc:TabView.TabStripHeader>
            <muxc:TabView.TabStripFooter>
                <Grid x:Name="CustomDragRegion" Background="#F3F3F3" />
            </muxc:TabView.TabStripFooter>
        </muxc:TabView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I need to get current tab type in MainTabbar.xaml.cs (it's ok). And then change Command Bar in Toolbar.xaml frame.
I wrote this procedure for change frame in Toolbar.xaml.cs:

```
        public void setMetCmdbarMode()
        {
            toolbarFrame.Navigate(typeof(MethodToolbar), null);
        }
```

But I don't know how I can call this function from MainTabbar class, or how I can translate tab type to Toolbar class.

Comment: It will be better if you could share some code about your real scenario. It's hard to say how to do it because we don't know how you implement your page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I updated main post

Comment: Do you mean when the TabView has changed its selected Item in the MainTabbar page, you want to change the content of the Toolbar usercontrol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking your code, you could try to create a custom event in the **MainTabbar**, and handle it in the **MainPage**. This event is triggered when the selected item of the TabView is changed. Then you could get notified in the MainPage and call method to change the **Toolbar**.

Here are the detailed steps:

1. Create a custom Event named `TabItemChanged` on the **MainTabbar page** and call it in the TabView_SelectionChanged event.
2. Handle the `TabItemChanged` in the **MainPage**
3. Change the content of the **Toolbar** as you want in the EventHandler based on the TabViewItem.

Code in **MainTabbar**:

```
  public sealed partial class MainTabbar : Page
{
    public event EventHandler TabItemChanged;

    public MainTabbar()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Tabs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.TabItemChanged != null)
            this.TabItemChanged(Tabs.SelectedItem, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

In the **MainPage.Xaml**

```
   <local:MainTabbar TabItemChanged="MainTabbar_TabItemChanged"/>
```

In the **MainPage.Xaml.cs**

```
 private void MainTabbar_TabItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MUXC.TabViewItem tabitem = sender as MUXC.TabViewItem;

        switch (tabitem.Tag) 
        {
            case "123":

                Debug.WriteLine("FirstItemSelectecd");
                //call method for toobar to change content 
                //like setMetCmdbarMode()

                break;

            case "234":

                Debug.WriteLine("SecondItemSelectecd");
                //call method for toobar to change content 
                //like setMetCmdbarMode()

                break;
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

Give the toolbar a name in MainPage.Xaml

```
  <local:Toolbar x:Name="myToolbar" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

Then call it in the MainPage.Xam.cs:

```
 switch (tabitem.Tag) 
        {
            case "123":

                Debug.WriteLine("FirstItemSelectecd");

                myToolbar.setMetCmdbarMode();
                break;

            case "234":

                Debug.WriteLine("SecondItemSelectecd");
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But how I can call method (setMetCmdBarMode) from Toolbar class (Toolbar.xaml.cs) in MainPage?

Comment: @BiryukovGeorgy Since you've already made that method a public method, you just need to give the ToolBar a name in the MainPage and call `myToolbar.setMetCmdbarMode();` in the event hander. You could check my update